# Nodejs - socket.io e jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, socket.io

Boa tarde

Estou seguindo o [tutorial inicial do socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) e está tudo funcionando, mas não entendi porque o jquery só funciona se chamar o script no html

Tentei instalar pelo npm e não funciona (a mensagem não loga)

Achei que package.json servisse justamente pra não ter que chamar o script no html

Ou para usar pelo npm eu deveria ter tirado o script do html, colocando em um arquivo a parte?

Podem explicar melhor como isso funciona?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Olá, Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
      //load socket.io-client
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

já que está usando node.js uma opção é tira-lo do html e incluí-lo em um arquivo à parte e criar uma variável contento o símbolo $ usado no jquery (não esqueça de ter incluído jquery no seu package.json ou executado o comando `npm install --save jquery`

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

Comment: ok, então é só porque estou abrindo tag script no arquivo html mesmo? o html não pega o que tá no package.json

Comment: no caso ele vai criar um conflito pois terão 2 jquerys 1 do pacote baixado através do npm e outro que você colocou no html (baixado através de um cdn)

Comment: então, eu tirei o do cdn e instalei pelo npm, aí não funcionou mais

Comment: você declarou como variável em um arquivo a parte? sua tag <script> realmente não irá funcionar, porém como está usando node.js você pode tirar a tag de script e incluir um arquivo .js que contem o conteúdo do script que deseja executar (o npm instala bilbiotecas/pacotes que somente podem ser chamados em arquivos javascript)

Comment: não, eu não havia declarado. vou alterar aqui pra testar dessa forma. obrigada